# How to identify Excel 4.0 Macro?

Tags: excel, vba, macros, excel-4.0

We were trying to Sign an Excel Macro, but got an error that it contains Excel 4.0 Macros and hence it can't proceed to sign them. [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141471(v=office.10).aspx) it won't allow Excel 4.0 Macro's but we couldn't find ways to identify Excel 4.0 Macros.

How to identify if a Macro is Excel 4.0 or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a macro is written in VBA using code editor, it is not an Excel 4.0 macro.

Excel 4.0 macro is a bunch of commands on a sheet.
You might have a formula somewhere... See [an example](http://www.excelforum.com/1958536-post3.html).